# ¿Cómo puedo usar una subcarpeta como dominio principal en PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache, servidor

Estoy virtualizando un dominio, **prueba.local** y me encuentro haciendo la siguiente parte de mi página, la cual se tiene que mostrar su funcionalidad, de ésta manera,  **prueba.local/ganadores**, en la que ganadores es la otra parte de la página. El problema es que como estoy virtualizando con *Apache*, yo tengo, por ejemplo **prueba.com**, pero necesito que al redireccionar a **prueba.com/ganadores**, entonces, sea sea tratado como el **HTTP_HOST** y no como la **URI** al usar `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

Por el momento, la parte de **ganadores** me causa problemas de funcionalidad por lo que comento, y por eso necesito hacer ese ***renombramiento*** sin que se vea afectado **prueba.com**.

**Nota:** Si yo hago un `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, me trae solo la parte de **ganadores**, y eso es lo que me da problemas. Por eso necesito que sea tratado como la raíz del proyecto, solo con esa parte de la subcarpeta.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que la raíz del proyecto sea una subcarpeta del mismo, sólo tienes que añadir la ruta de la subcarpeta en la propiedad `document_root` del vhost que corresponda.

Si quieres tener dos vhost, uno para el primer proyecto (`prueba.local`), no puedes tener otro vhost cuyo nombre lleve slashes (e.g. `prueba.local/ganadores`).

Lo más indicado para tu caso de uso es que uses **subdominios**. Un vhost `ganadores.prueba.local` cuyo document root sea la subcarpeta `ganadores`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/prueba"
    ServerName prueba.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/prueba/ganadores"
    ServerName ganadores.prueba.local
</VirtualHost>
```